# Separating icons from pictures in a bunch of random PNGs

Tags: image, algorithm, sorting

A long time ago I screwed with my HDD and had to recover all my data, but I couldn't recover the files' names.

I used a tool to sort all these files by extension, and another to sort the JPGs by date, since the date when a JPG was created is stored in the file itself. I can't do this with PNGs, though, unfortunately.

So I have a ***lot*** of PNGs, but most of them are just icons or assets used formerly as data by the software I used at that time. But I know there are other, "real" pictures, that are valuable to me, and I would really love to get them back.

I'm looking for any tool, or any way, just anything you can think of, that would help me separate the trash from the good in this bunch of pictures, it would really be *amazing* of you.

Just so you know, I'm speaking of 230 thousand files, for ~2GB of data.

As an exemple, this is what I call trash :
[image: An icon for something I don't care about] or [image: Another one], [image: Again] and all these kind of images.
I'd like these to be separated from pictures of landscapes / people / screenshots, the kind of pictures you could have in you phone's gallery...

Thanks for reading, I hope you'll be able to help !

Comment: I'm not sure the exact algorithm since I don't know the language you are using but just sort them so that if the image size is bigger than 150px and height is bigger than 150px it's probably not an icon and can be moved to the pictures folder. This will only let some through that can be quickly swept up afterwards. PNG does output its width and height variables as does jpg

Comment: @Kaboom I'm actually currently not programming anymore (I don't have the time unfortunately) but I'll try to do it in bash... Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Why would you store natural images as png? Especially when they came from a phone. This makes no sense. But if you are interested in looking for these; just go for filesize or number_of_pixels. This will be a good classifier for natural vs. icon.

Comment: @sascha I don't know why they are PNGs, it's, for the most part, very old pictures... And thanks, I think I'll use the size of file and picture.

Comment: Okay and one more approach for natural vs. icon: count the number of colors. Most icons only use very few. But this needs programming.

Comment: @sascha Wouldn't it be too much time expensive ? And do you think I could do it in bash ?

Comment: IO will be slower than the calculations needed. No, bash will not be enough, except if something like ImageMagick will be able to output this kind of info (which is actually possible). (But i automatically thought of a few lines python doing this).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136173/discussion-between-abehssera-yohan-and-sascha).

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Not sure it still matters, but the answer is Windows 10. I use bash on Windows though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple ImageMagick command will tell you the:

- height
- width
- number of colours
- name

of every PNG in the current directory, separated by colons for easy parsing:

```
convert *.png -format "%h:%w:%k:%f\n"  info:
```

**Sample Output**

```
600:450:5435:face.png
600:450:17067:face_sobel_magnitude.png
2074:856:2:lottery.png
450:450:1016:mask.png
450:450:7216:result.png
600:450:5435:scratches.png
800:550:471:spectrum.png
752:714:20851:z.png
```

If you are on macOS or Linux, you can easily run it under **GNU Parallel** to get 16 done at a time and you can parse the results easily with `awk`, but you may be on Windows.

You may want to change the `\n` at the end for `\r\n` under Windows if you are planning to parse the output.

Comment: That's a very good answer, thank you. I had already managed with the help of the people in the comments to use only the number of colors, and I ended with running `identify -format %k $filename` for each file, and selecting files with a value greater than 5000. It worked well, I might use the other values later.